# Automatically add a number of row cells and subtract a 3rd row over a variable number of columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I have the following function that automatically sums 3 rows together for a specified number of cells determined by D2:

`=BYCOL((INDEX($1:$11,{4;5;10},SEQUENCE(1,D2,COLUMN(I:I)))),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))`

The values in each column in rows 4 and 5 I wish to add together and I'd like to subtract the result from the cell value for row 10. I have a workaround which sets the values in row 10 to negative but I'd prefer them to be positive numbers.

I tried the following, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

`=BYCOL((INDEX($1:$11,{4;5;10},SEQUENCE(1,D2,COLUMN(I:I)))),LAMBDA(x,y,z,SUM((x+y)-z)))`

Example of expected result:

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Revenue | 10000 | 12000 | 14000 | 16000 | 11000 | 20000 | 21000 | 22000 | 24000 |
| Extra Revenue | 1000 | 2000 | 3000 | 1000 | 2000 | 2000 | 1000 | 1500 | 2500 |
| Costs | 500 | 1000 | 2000 | 500 | 1000 | 1000 | 750 | 1000 | 1000 |
| Profit/Loss | 10500 | 13000 | 15000 | 16500 | 12000 | 21000 | 21250 | 22500 | 25500 |

Comment: Can you provide some sample data plus expected output - preferably via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: hey Ike, I have used the generator, I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for though? The ByCol function would be in the first cell of the Profit/Loss and auto calculate for the length determined by D2 in my case.

Comment: And where is row 10 in your sample data? What is the value of D2?

Comment: Revenue will be row 4, extra revenue row 5 and costs row 10. D2 can be variable but atm is 25. So to adjust the function for the sample data above you'd have `=BYCOL((INDEX($1:$11,{2;3;4},SEQUENCE(1,4,COLUMN(I:I)))),LAMBDA(x,y,z,SUM((x+y)-z)))` assuming SUM((x+y)-z) actually worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it match with your data:

```
=BYCOL((INDEX($1:$11,{2;3;4},SEQUENCE(1,Q2,COLUMN(B:B)))),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(x,1)+INDEX(x,2)-INDEX(x,3)))
```

where I've put a suitable value (9) into Q2.

[image]

*EDIT*

This would have been tidier

```
=BYCOL((INDEX($1:$11,{2;3;4},SEQUENCE(1,Q2,COLUMN(B:B)))),LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(x,{1;1;-1})))
```

Answer (score 2):

Different approach - but in my eyes the formula is more readable for what you want to achieve:

[image]

The red part is named 'rowHeader', the blue part 'data'

```
=LET(revenue,FILTER(data,rowHeader="Revenue"),
extraRevenue,FILTER(data,rowHeader="extra Revenue"),
costs,FILTER(data,rowHeader="Costs"),
revenue + extraRevenue-costs)
```

UPDATE:

You can define the ranges also within the LET-formula

[image]

```
=LET(rowHeader,A6:A15,
data,MAKEARRAY(10,B2,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(6:15,r,c+1))),
revenue,FILTER(data,rowHeader="Revenue"),
extraRevenue,FILTER(data,rowHeader="extra Revenue"),
costs,FILTER(data,rowHeader="Costs"),
revenue+extraRevenue-costs)
```

B2 contains the number of months that should be returned.

Comment: Hey Ike, I've used Tom's suggestion below, however I do like the look of the suggestion. Could you let me know how I define the data part which can be variable and also how I define the rowHeader please?

Comment: Updated the answer - to define the range within the LET-formula

Comment: Is it possible for L15 to be defined based on the value in B2?

Comment: Just define the max possible number of columns  e.g. ZZ15

Comment: Or use `MAKEARRAY(10,B2,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(6:15,r,c+1)))` for `data`